# what is the difference between entity id and increment id in sales_order table

Tags: orders, sales-order, sales, increment-id

which id should be used for order status update. How should the status be updated?

Answer (score 1):

**Entity Id (entity_id column name in table)  is the primary key which is used for the table to keep unique id per row and its auto-increment so when a new row is generated/inserted automatically generate latest id.**

Increment id (increment_id column name in table) is for Order purpose. It's used for order fetching/display information of a specific order based on the increment id.

**Increment ID is also used for third party API to connect order related stuff to another platform.**

You can also change the default behavior of Increment id as per your requirement.
**Like 000000001 to T000000001.**

Comment: Is there possibility to change order `entity_id`?